# Can I sell subscriptions without subscription button using Pay Pal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have website on which I want to sell subscriptions. Here is the scenario:

In the pricing tables there is button purchase. When user click on the button I am sending him to the form where he can enter his details (name, email, password) . When visitor click on the submit button his account is created and I want to redirect him to the pay-pal page, where the user can make the payment.

Can anyone point me to some article on pay-pal page where I can read instructions how can I do that, and which model/api/gateway/whatever I should use for that? I know how to create subscription buttons, but using them doesn't seem to fit in my scenario-flow. Please note that I need help to FIND information how this can be done, I will find my way with the coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal supports multiple ways to sell subscriptions.
You can use one of these depending on type of complexity you can handle and features you want:

1. PayPal WPS Subscription Buttons
   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#recurring-payment-variables

This is a button integration, you can specify your subscription terms and PayPal will take care of making recurring payments. You can also maintain inventory, profile & loss tracking. This will require very less coding effort from your end.

2. API Integration: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans-and-agreements/

This is an API integration: Here you need to create a Plan and redirect the buyer to paypal to get buyer's approval. Then you can do recurring payments via API calls. You will need to maintain a secure database of approval ids, buyer details and the agreement details. Also you will need a daemon which should call PayPal apis on subscription dates.

You can also refer to this guide to get more info on different flows supported by paypal: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/directory/

Answer (score 0):

Both Paypal doc links are 404.